# SaveMode is not working in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was running Spark SQL example with SaveMode option but getting following error.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("json").load("/user/root/spark/data/people.json")
df.select("name","age").write.format("json").save("Output",SaveMode.ErrorIfExist)


<console>:35: error: overloaded method value save with alternatives:
  ()Unit <and>
  (path: String)Unit
 cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode)
              df.select("name", "age").write.format("json").save("Output",SaveMode.ErrorIfExists
```

I checked documentation , it says SaveMode is deprecated. How do I fix this?

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `DataFrameWriter.mode` method:

```
df.write.mode("error").save(...)
```

or

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.ErrorIfExists).save(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for help.

I am using scala for development and when i used SaveMode.ErrorIfExists , it is not working but mode as "error" it works perfectly. Apache Spark SQL documentations says that SaveMode.ErrorIfExists is accepted for scala/java which does not seems to happen. Any idea?

Comment: @Shashi use import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode . Then try df.write.mode(SaveMode.ErrorIfExists).save(...)